# minSdkVersion 8 cannot be smaller than version 9 declared in library - post AdMob

Tags: android, android-studio, libgdx, admob, google-play-services

I've added the ability to enter admob classes in my project with Android Studio , as well .:

[image]

The problem is that since I added this option , I go into conflict sdk credo..non are very handy Android sorry.

[image]

How can I fix the problem ? I should then bring up an interstitial banner :

> InterstitialAd interstitialAd ;

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mygame.game.android"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/GdxTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.mygame.game.android.AndroidLauncher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Error:

> Error:(7, 5) uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 8 cannot be smaller than version 9
>   declared in library C:\Users\myuser\Documents\my
>   game\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-ads\8.4.0\AndroidManifest.xml
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':android:processDebugManifest'.
>
> > Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 8 cannot be smaller than version 9 declared in library
> >     C:\Users\myuser\Documents\mygame\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-ads\8.4.0\AndroidManifest.xml
> >       Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.android.gms.ads" to
> >     force usage

how to solve ???

Comment: Try opening your SDK Manager and checking whether you have downloaded the libraries for Android API Level lower than 9. You probably don't unless you've manually added them.

Comment: Try changing `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"` to `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9"`

Answer (score 1):

This error is telling you that the `play-services-ads` library (aka AdMob) supports a minimum SDK of 9, but your application is trying to declare a min SDK of 8.

Since that library only supports back to version 9, your application cannot support anything older than that.

> how to solve ???

Either stop supporting version 8 of Android ([which currently accounts for just .1% of users globally](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html)), or remove the ads library.